# Attaching additional queries to webforms

Tags: 6, webforms

I'd like to limit the ability of a form submission based on whether a user has submitted the form already.

So basically if a user has submitted a form, they can not submit again.
I've already created the form using webforms, I just need to figure out how to limit the submissions now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webform has already this option, that you can find in the Submission settings. Otherwise, if you need to check something more you still can use some Webform [hooks](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-3.x:/webform_hooks.php).

But if you need more complex submission checking, the best way from my point of view is to add a `validate` callback with the help of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6).

**Edit**

Here is an example how to use the hook_form_alter(); For it, you must install the module [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) before.

```
// First you have to create your module
// you will find more information about it
// here http://drupal.org/node/231276
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // To add your validate callback to any form, you must find
  // the right form_id before
  // the form_id is an id that identify the form
  // from all that drupal can generate.
  // My solution to find it quickly its to show
  // all form_id with the help of Devel
  dsm($form, $form_id);
  // This will show you a drupal_set_message with something like that
  // form_id_form => Array()…
  // When you found the form that you want add the validate callback you
  // change it like that
  if($form_id == 'the_form_id') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_myvalidate';
  }
}

function mymodule_myvalidate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Here you can see want you receive
  // by checking the content of $form_state
  // still with Devel, like that
  dsm($form_state);

  // You should see the values in $form_state['values']
  // After you can make your additional checks and retur errors like that
  if($error) {
    form_set_error('field_error', t("You can balbla"));
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but my understanding of hooks is still a little shakey. Do I just create a random module and use the hook within a new module?

Comment: Before to think about hooks, is it enough the built-in feature that allow user submit only one time your formulae or you need more checks ?

Comment: I need more checks as well. I need to check it against another table to see if the user is involved in certain projects.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope its can help you.

Comment: I think that's gonna help me get going on this issue. Thank you so much!